# Title color of UIButton won't change on highlighted/selected but background color will

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

This has been a very odd process.

I have an IBOutletCollection of UIButtons. I loop through the collection and create them like this (the `displayHourButtons` is called from `viewWillAppear`):

```
- (void)displayHourButtons
{
    // Counter
    NSUInteger b = 0;

    // Set attributes
    UIFont *btnFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Metric-Semibold" size:13.0];
    UIColor *btnTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(147/255.0f) green:(147/255.0f) blue:(147/255.0f) alpha:1.0];
    NSNumber *btnTracking = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.25];
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *btnStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    [btnStyle setLineSpacing:2.0];

    NSDictionary *btnAttrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              btnFont, NSFontAttributeName,
                              btnTextColor, NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                              btnTracking, NSKernAttributeName, nil];

    // CREATE THE BUTTONS
    for (UIButton *hourButton in hourButtons) {
            // I'm using the attributed string for something else
            // later in development that I haven't got to yet. 
            // I simplified the string for this example's sake.
        NSString *btnTitleText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %lu", (unsigned long)b];

        NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
                                                     initWithString:btnTitleText
                                                     attributes:btnAttrs];

        [attributedText addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                               value:btnStyle
                               range:NSMakeRange(0, btnTitleText.length)];


        CALayer *btnLayer = [hourButton layer];
        [btnLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        [btnLayer setCornerRadius:19.0f];
        [hourButton setTag:b];
        [hourButton setContentEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
        [hourButton setAttributedTitle:attributedText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [hourButton setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter];
        [hourButton setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
        hourButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        [hourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showHour:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 

        b++;
    }
}
```

When one of the buttons is clicked, per the action `showHour:` is called:

```
- (IBAction)showHour:(id)sender
{
    [self.hourButtons enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)obj;

        if (button != sender && button.enabled) {
                // This is applied. I know because I tested it with redColor
            [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

            // Doesn't change, stays the gray set initially
            [button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else {
                // This is applied
            [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(169/255.0f) green:(234/255.0f) blue:(255/255.0f) alpha:1.0]];

            // This is not
            [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:(UIControlStateNormal | UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted)];
        }
    }];

    // displayHour uses the tag to change labels, images, etc.
    [self displayHour:(long int)[sender tag]];
}
```

I tried all sorts of crazy things to get the UIImage to be in a selected state, but nothing worked. This enumerateObjects deal is the only thing that has worked. That's why I say this has been an odd process. I guess buttons don't stay active indefinitely?

Anyways, **MY QUESTION**: Is there a certain reason why the title color isn't changing? Just the background? I suspect it has something to do with the background not being set initially, but I couldn't explain why.

Thanks!

**UPDATED**

Per @Timothy Moose's answer, below is the updated code.

```
- (IBAction)showHour:(id)sender
{   
    [self.hourButtons enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)obj;

        // Grab the mutable string from the button and make a mutable copy
        NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[button attributedTitleForState:UIControlStateNormal] mutableCopy];

        // Shared attribute styles
        UIFont *btnFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Metric-Semibold" size:14.0];
        NSNumber *btnTracking = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.25];
        NSMutableParagraphStyle *btnStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
        [btnStyle setLineSpacing:2.0];

        // Since we can't set a color directly on a Attributed string we have
        // to make a new attributed string.
        if (button != sender && button.enabled) {
            // Return to the default color
            UIColor *btnTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(147/255.0f) green:(147/255.0f) blue:(147/255.0f) alpha:1.0];

            // Set up attributes
            NSDictionary *btnAttrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      btnFont, NSFontAttributeName,
                                      btnTextColor, NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                      btnTracking, NSKernAttributeName, nil];

            // Reapply the default color (for the one button that was changed to white)
            [attributedText setAttributes:btnAttrs
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length)];

            // Add line-height
            [attributedText addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                                   value:btnStyle
                                   range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length)];

            // Reset default attributes
            [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            [button setAttributedTitle:attributedText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else {
            // Our new white color for the active button
            UIColor *btnTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            // Set up attributes
            NSDictionary *btnAttrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      btnFont, NSFontAttributeName,
                                      btnTextColor, NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                      btnTracking, NSKernAttributeName, nil];

            // Apply our new white color
            [attributedText setAttributes:btnAttrs
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length)];

            // Add line-height
            [attributedText addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                                   value:btnStyle
                                   range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length)];

            // Add new attributes for active button
            [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(169/255.0f) green:(234/255.0f) blue:(255/255.0f) alpha:1.0]];
            [button setAttributedTitle:attributedText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }];

    [self displayHour:(long int)[sender tag]];
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`setTitleColor` doesn't have any effect when the title is an attributed string. Either use a plain `NSString` or call `setAttributedTitle` again after applying the desired color to the attributed string.

Answer (score 20):

Also it is very important not to have the button on System style, just put it on custom...
This is for similar questions, not for this particular question.

Comment: What really is the difference between a system style button and a custom style button? The documentation seems vague on this aspect. For one, making it custom style removes tintColor being used as the text color. What other differences are there? Thank you.

Comment: This is actually a **remarkably important tip**, thanks Catalin!  truss, there seems to be many subtle differences.  for example, there is (annoyingly!) no equivalent function, regarding the TEXT, for adjustsImageWhenHighlighted.  essentially, you must use "custom" to achieve "adjustsTEXTWhenHighlighted=false".  and other subtle examples!

Comment: trss probably the way is drawn and some inner bugs inside the system most likely

Comment: In my very odd case, I changed the button from custom to system style, and that somehow solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I created a custom class **MyButton** extended from `UIButton`. Then added this inside the `Identity Inspector`:

[image]

After this, change the button type to **Custom**:

[image]

Then you can set attributes like `textColor` and `UIFont` for your `UIButton` for the different states:

[image]

Then I also created two methods inside `MyButton` class which I have to call inside my code when I want a `UIButton` to be displayed as highlighted:

```
- (void)changeColorAsUnselection{
    [self setTitleColor:[UIColor colorFromHexString:acColorGreyDark] 
               forState:UIControlStateNormal & 
                        UIControlStateSelected & 
                        UIControlStateHighlighted];
}

- (void)changeColorAsSelection{
    [self setTitleColor:[UIColor colorFromHexString:acColorYellow] 
               forState:UIControlStateNormal & 
                        UIControlStateHighlighted & 
                        UIControlStateSelected];
}
```

You have to set the `titleColor` for normal, highlight and selected `UIControlState` because there can be more than one state at a time according to the documentation of `UIControlState`.
If you don't create these methods, the `UIButton` will display selection or highlighting but they won't stay in the `UIColor` you setup inside the `UIInterface Builder` because they are just available for a short display of a selection, not for displaying selection itself.

Comment: Isn't that should be an OR instead of AND

Comment: In this case, you have to set it to all these states because a button has so many. Otherwise it would be possible it changes the color on one of these states and in the end it changes the color too often and looks like a bug. Might also be possible the solution is just applicable on the problem I have.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using XCode 7.x.

I faced up with the similar problem. After using NSAttributedString

```
let underlineAttribute = [NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue]
        let underlineAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "FILTER", attributes: underlineAttribute)
        filterButton.setTitleColor(AppConfig.FOREGROUND, forState: .Normal)
        filterButton.setAttributedTitle(underlineAttributedString, forState: .Normal)
```

the filterButton.setTitleColor(AppConfig.FOREGROUND, forState: .Normal) not get effected.

I change the Tint Color of the button in the Interface Builder (which is default as light blue). Now, it works for me now.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the above answers is to apply the text colour using string attributes. You can set a different NSAttributedString for each control state, so this works to achieve the same effect - the button text will change colour on select/highlight.

Example:

```
// We're assuming attributedString already exists - this is your completed attributed string so far
// We're going to copy this string into two more NS(Mutable)AttributedString variables - one for the "normal" state and one for the "highlighted" state
NSMutableAttributedString *normalAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:attributedString];
// Set the desired foreground color (in this case it's for the "normal" state) for the length of the string
[normalAttributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blackColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,attributedString.length)];

// Rinse and repeat for the highlighted state
NSMutableAttributedString *highlightedAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:attributedString];
[highlightedAttributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,attributedString.length)];

// Finally, we'll set these as the attributedTitles for the relevant control states.
[myButton setAttributedTitle:normalAttributedString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setAttributedTitle:highlightedAttributedString forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[myButton setAttributedTitle:highlightedAttributedString forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Answer (score -2):

I noticed this immediately. Just a simple error probably :)

Change

```
UIColor *btnTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(147/255.f) 
                                        green:(147/255.f) 
                                         blue:(147/255.f) alpha:1.0];
```

to

```
UIColor *btnTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(147/255.0f) 
                                        green:(147/255.0f) 
                                         blue:(147/255.0f) alpha:1.0];
```

The reason it wasn't changing is probably because it wasn't recognizing the `UIColor` since you didn't have a full number in the division, since it was seeing **(147/255.)** instead of **(147/255.0)**

Comment: That was definitely a bug, thanks. But I'm still having the same issue once I fix the color values. They stay the originally set light gray and don't change to white. I've updated the original code with your color fix though.

Comment: why don't you set the text color in for (UIButton *hourButton in hourButtons) loop? that way it finds the button…just do [hourButton setTitleColor:btnTextColor forState:UIControlStateNormal]; to test it, and then change forState to whatever other state you need later

Comment: Hey, see answer above. It was because I was using an attributed string.

Comment: ah, well I wouldn't have known that anyways haha glad you got your answer! :)